# Backstretch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add backstretch on my webpage, as a image slideshow (`body` background)
But it doesn't work!!
 The only code I used is this one: (I added it before `</head>`)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*
 * Here is an example of how to use Backstretch as a slideshow.
 * Just pass in an array of images, and optionally a duration and fade value.
 */

  // Duration is the amount of time in between slides,
  // and fade is value that determines how quickly the next image will fade in
  $.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
  ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
</script>
```

What's the problem here? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backstretch isn't part of the default jquery library.  Have you loaded it separately?

I've done so in this snippet, and your code seems to work:

```js
$.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.3/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
```